# Is my answer correct for $\int \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos^3(x)} \;\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

I said $\frac{\tan^2(x)}{2} + c$ but my book says $\frac{1}{2\cos^2(x)} + c$

Comment: You can always check your integrations by differentiating; what is the derivative of $1/2\tan^2x+c$?

Comment: The two functions $\frac{\tan^2 x}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2\cos^2 x}$ differ by a constant. Both answers are right.

Comment: An illustration of the importance of knowing your trig identities: you'll run into need of them from time to time when working among trigonometric integrals.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$
\frac{1}{2 \cos^2{x}}
= \frac{\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x)}{2 \cos^2(x)}
= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sin^2(x)}{2 \cos^2(x)}
= \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \tan^2(x)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes your answer is correct, all your book did was use some trig identities to manipulate the answer a little, the main trig identities they used were:
$$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x) = 1$$ $$\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)} = \tan(x)$$

Using the second identity we get that your answer:

$$\frac{\tan^2(x)}{2} = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{2\cos^2(x)}$$

If we manipulate the first equation to say:
$$\sin^2(x) = 1-\cos^2(x)$$ we get

$$\frac{\tan^2(x)}{2} = \frac{\sin^2(x)}{2\cos^2(x)}$$
$$= \frac{1-\cos^2(x)}{2\cos^2(x)}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2\cos^2(x)} - \frac{\cos^2(x)}{2cos^2(x)}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2\cos^2(x)} - \frac{1}{2}$$

If you recall, the 'plus $c$' part of the antiderivative is just a constant and here the constant is $-\frac{1}{2}$. Because they differ by just a constant, both answers are correct.